# Definition of early vs. late transition metal

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, periodic-table

Is there an *accepted* definition of an early or late transition metal? I think the late transition metals start at Group 8 (including Fe), but others have said Fe is not a late transition metal. I'm just curious if this is a matter of preference based on one's field of study or if there is a generally accepted definition.

Comment: Iron could count as an early example of the late transition metals (e.g. by https://harnedgroup.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/introductiontometals.pdf), but maybe IUPAC has deposit its definition outside the color books.

Comment: Yes, that figure is my conventional understanding of what an inorganic chemist might call early, middle, and late transition metals. Still, I'm not sure if it's IUPAC says otherwise (or if there are other fields where this classification scheme would not be accepted).

Comment: Why would you want to say that iron is a late transition metal? Groups 11&12 are very different from 6-10. I don't think that'd be a very useful definition.

Comment: The reason why is largely irrelevant to the question. But yes, Fe and Cu are extremely differently electronically (and Zn is often not even classified as a transition metal, at least according to IUPAC).